# Ant mail task logs

Tags: email, ant

I'm trying to run the ant mail task and the script works fine in my cygwin but when I move it over to ubuntu I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/admin/test/build.xml:22: mail doesn't support the "enableStartTLS" attribute
```

Then I removed that attribute and got:

```
[mail] Failed to initialize MIMI mail: javax/mail/MessagingException
```

I was wondering where I can find some sort of log or force a log somehow. Any ideas? Here is the ant task:

```
<mail mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" user="####" password="####" enableStartTLS="true" subject="jMeter test results from nightly build.">
<from address="codeslikeamonkey@ga.com"/>
<to address="codeslikeamonkey@ga.com"/>
<message>This is an automated message containing results from the most recent discovery build.</message>
<attachments>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="JMeter-Results*"/>
    </fileset>
</attachments>
</mail>
```

Comment: Are you sure both platforms use the same ant installation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first error message suggests that you have different versions of the mail task between Windows and Ubuntu.  Run "ant -version" on both systems to check.

Make sure also when running Ant that you have $JAVA_HOME pointing to a full JDK installation, not just a JRE.  askubuntu.com has plenty of info on how to install a JDK if you need help.

Comment: Awesome idea, they are different versions. When I did ant -version on the ubuntu box I got an "Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /opt/jre.../tols.jar" Then I got the version number.

Comment: Edited answer with some extra diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have activation.jar and javax.mail.jar in ant/lib directory in order to execute the ant target